# unable to refresh ng-table after $http call.

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

in my SPA i have an activate function which has a promise getNodes()

```
        function activate() {
        var promises = [getNodes()];
        common.activateController(promises, controllerId)
            .then(function () { log('Activated Nodes List View'); });
    }
```

getNodes() call to database to fetch list of 'Node' and i am making a grouped ng-table out of it.

```
    function getNodes() {
        return datacontext.getNodes().then(function (response) {
            $scope.data = response.data;
            $scope.$watch("query", function () {

                $scope.tableParams.reload();
            });
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // show first page
                count: 10,          // count per page
                sorting: {
                    name: 'asc'
                }
            }, {
                groupBy: function (item) {

                    return item.NodeGroup.Name;
                },

                total: $scope.data,
                getData: function ($defer, params) {

                    var filteredData = new Array();
                    var func = (function () {
                        $scope.data.forEach(function (node) {
                            var is = !!((node.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.query || '') !== -1) || (node.IP.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.query || '') !== -1) || (node.NodeGroup.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.query || '') !== -1));
                            if (is) {
                                filteredData.push(node);
                            }
                        });
                    })();

                    var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                        $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                                         filteredData;

                    $scope.tableParams.total(orderedData.length);//this is also nto working for me. 
                    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                },
                $scope: $scope
            });
        });

    }
```

whats happening is that when id add a node it does not update my table. If i refresh the page i can see the newly added node. But i want my table to refresh soon after this addition.

After adding a node i am calling activate again but it didn't worked.

```
    function addNode(node) {
        return datacontext.addNode(node).then(function (response) {
            activate();
        });
```

after some research i added the line below.

```
            $scope.tableParams.total(orderedData.length);
```

this also didn't worked for me. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to fix my Add and update simply by updating my add and Update fictions.

In the case of add i am pushing the newly added object into $scope.data after successful server call to Add, and then calling

$scope.tableParams.reload();

In the case of update i am finding the the object to update by its Id and replacing it with the updated object after successful call to Update, and then calling  $scope.tableParams.reload();

But my question is, was this the best way to do this refresh of ng-table or i am missing something ?

```
    function addNode(node) {
        return datacontext.addNode(node).then(function (response) {
            $scope.data.push(node);
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
            //activate();
        });

    }
```

and

```
        function updateNode(node) {
        return datacontext.updateNode(node).then(function (response) {
            $scope.data.forEach(function (old) {
                var is = old.Id == node.Id;
                if (is) {
                    var index = $scope.data.indexOf(old);
                    $scope.data[index] = node;
                }
            });
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        });

    }
```